# Return Array in a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, helpermethods

Why can't I return an array in a helper method?

```
def childrenOf(a)
    @children = Post.find_by_parent_id(a.id)        
    return @children 
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

Use `find_all_by_parent_id` instead.

And you don't need the second line.

The following is enough.

```
def childrenOf(a)
  @children  = Post.find_all_by_parent_id(a.id)        
end
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. You are a life saver :) I love this platform

Comment: Glad to help you. Could you please upvote my answer and accept it as an correct?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 instead of using `find_all_by` use `where`:

```
def childrenOf(a)
  @children  = Post.where(:parent_id => a.id)        
end
```